Android gradle build failure
My current android application has multiple git repos.
one of which is the current production version being employed by all our users.
another of which is our dev branch where we add new features etc.
Lately we have been heavily focused on major updates on the dev repo which is building and launching fine.
One of my colleagues attempted to build the prodcution repo and it failed with a multiple errors of this type shown below:-
FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform EasyFlipView-2.1.2.aar (com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:2.1.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find EasyFlipView-2.1.2.aar (com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:2.1.2).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView/EasyFlipView/2.1.2/EasyFlipView-2.1.2.aar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView/EasyFlipView/2.1.2/EasyFlipView-2.1.2.jar
   > Failed to transform flexbox-2.0.1.aar (com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find flexbox-2.0.1.aar (com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.aar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.jar
   > Failed to transform awesome-calendar-1.1.3.aar (com.archit.calendar:awesome-calendar:1.1.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find awesome-calendar-1.1.3.aar (com.archit.calendar:awesome-calendar:1.1.3).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/archit/calendar/awesome-calendar/1.1.3/awesome-calendar-1.1.3.aar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/archit/calendar/awesome-calendar/1.1.3/awesome-calendar-1.1.3.jar

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

this is odd for a number of reasons.
1). No changes have been applied to the production repo since we last released.
2). the dependencies in the production repo and dev repo are IDENTICAL.
3). Not all my colleagues are experiencing this build issue.

what we have refactored in the dev repo is that we replaced buildSrc with build-logic
however as i stated, the producution repo has not had any changes applied since we last published a release version to our users.
what could be the root cause of this build issue for "some" of my colleagues?
why would a repo that has built fine with no issues previously with no changes what so ever made to it suddenly start to experience build issues.
it must be something outside of git, such as android settings, jdk versions, dev machine OS or something similar
how do i go about identifying the root cause?

jcenter no longer exists, you need to find alternatives locations for those libraries

Your colleagues' Gradle caches do not contain these artifacts. Those artifacts are no longer published, at least not with their original artifact group and ID. Flexbox 3.0.0 is available from google(). com.archit.calendar:awesome-calendar might be this, which has new dependency instructions. com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView is now on mavenCentral().

so does gradle have a cache per repo? as I said I can build our dev repo fine and not the production one. and they both have identical dependencies

on your computer if you were to go to your .gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-* folder you would see all the libraries that are cached, If you were to delete the cache folder from the devices that the build is working on you would then see the same error
